# Drag and Drop for Unity strategy game only works on 2 axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I'm currently working on a game with drag n drop controls.
The problem is the drag and drop only works on 2 axes.
The goal is to drag a `GameObject` across the map in all directions. The `GameObject` only needs to be lifted slightly (on the y axis).

How can I move the `GameObject` on all three axes?

This is the code:

```
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isDragging;

    public Vector3 mouse_offset;
    private float mouse_z_coord;
    private float mouse_y_coord;
    private float mouse_y_offset = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Debug.Log(rend);
        defaultColor = Color.yellow;
        mouseOverColor = Color.blue;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0,1,0);
        mouse_z_coord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).z;
        mouse_y_coord = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).y, 0, mouse_y_offset);
        
        mouse_offset = transform.position - GetMouseAsWorldPoint();
        isDragging = true;
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseAsWorldPoint() 
    {
        // Screenpoint coordinates of the mouse.
        Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;

        // z coordinate of dragged gameobject.
        mousePoint.z = mouse_z_coord;

        mousePoint.y = mouse_y_coord;

        // Convert to world space.
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
    }

    private void onMouseDrag() 
    {
        transform.position = GetMouseAsWorldPoint() + mouse_offset;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp() 
    {
        // Remove hardcode value.
        isDragging = false;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (isDragging) 
        {
            transform.position = GetMouseAsWorldPoint() + mouse_offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried this ->

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
        {
            transform.position = hit.point;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
        }
```

This should placed the object at the position of the ray coming from my mouse cursor but it didn't work.
The object gets dragged along the ray and bugs into the camera.

Here is a downloadlink for the UnityScene:
https://easyupload.io/wu76sj

Comment: What exactly does `but its not working.` mean? And are you sure you are hitting the correct object (floor)?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre]. This includes how to construct the hierarchy in the scene, and what components to attach to each gameobject. Voting to close until a [mre] is included in the question.